# Accessing a value inside a nested list and sending it too a function

Tags: python, function, loops

I am writing a blackjack game too teach myself python.
To represent the 52 cards in the deck I have a nested list within a list, this list contains its original place in the deck (0-51) it's suit and it's face value as a string. Within my function I deal my players cards and have the deck value(0-51) the suit value and the face value stored within a list. I am attempting to read the deck value into a function I created to evaluate the score of the players hand, however I am getting the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list. So I am not indexing correctly, but this seems to be the correct way to index to reach the first value of a list within a list, so I am stumped. Could you guys help me out.

Here is my function:

```
#this function evalutes the game value of a card and adds it to the players score
def card_value(card, value):

   if card%13 == 0 and value<=10:                      #Evaluate value of ace based on the value of the rest
      value +=11                                      # of the deck
   elif card%13 == 0 and value>10:
      value+=1
   elif card%13 == 10 or 11 or 12:                     # evaluate face cards
      value += 10
   else:
      value += card%13 +1                             #Evaluate rest of the cards in the deck
```

and here is my function call:

```
for _ in player1_hand:                              
     player1_score += card_value(player1_hand[_][0],player1_score)
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: `_` is each value from `player1_hand`, not each _index_ for it. Also, don't call a variable  `_`.

Comment: How `player1_hand` looks like?

Comment: Also, `card_value` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @khelwood actually, `_` is the preferred way in Python to indicate that you're not using a variable - typically that'd be used if looping over a range of integers if you don't actually care about the integers, but just want to repeat some operation some number of times

Comment: @RandomDavis but that's not what he's doing.  He's subsequently using the variable '_' and it isn't an integer.  It's a list (which is why he's getting the error he's getting).

Comment: @RandomDavis If that was what he was doing, I wouldn't have pointed it out.

Comment: @khelwood so what would write instead of "_".

Comment: @mad_ this is what player1_hand looks like: player1_hand = [], it is just an initialized list that I use a for loop to read card values into.

Comment: @RocketMan89 A variable name indicating the purpose of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the for loop function calling the individual card of player one's hand. I was indexing the list of lists, player1-hand, incorrectly. I fixed the indexing call, however the function is returning an incorrect hand value for player one's hand. I will fix the logic on the function and update later.

```
for _ in player1_hand:                              #use for loop to evaluate the value using function card_value
#print(_[1])                                    #proper indexing call.
player_card = _[0]
player1_score += card_value(player_card, player1_score)
```